# Which JavaScript WYSIWYG editor supports merge/custom fields?

Tags: wysiwyg, rte

I am looking at creating custom document creation for a Rails application. Users will have ability to edit HTML document. I want to include custom/merge fields from the data objects like {{property.contact.name}} in HTML code. Is there a javascript rich text editor that has this capability? I have been searching for a while but could not locate one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TinyMCE. This feature is called MergeTags. It's a plugin.